# Does Moshi crash if JSON response is extended with further items?

Tags: kotlin, moshi

The responses from my REST calls I parse to

```
inline fun <reified T> getJsonAdapter(): JsonAdapter<T> {
    return Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(T::class.java)
}
```

and then:

```
val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<MyPojos> = JsonAdapterBuilder.getJsonAdapter()
                    val jsonResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        jsonAdapter.fromJson(response.readText())
                    }
```

Assuming MyPojos data class is:

```
data class MyPojos(val a: String, val b: String)
```

and backend later responses with

```
{
    "a": 5,
    "b": 5,
    "c": 7
}
```

where response was extended to `c`..

Since I have no influence to backend, I can't test it.
**So would the new response with c crash ?**

Comment: If you want to test you can just use `jsonAdapter.fromJson` passing a string containing a test JSON. You don't need to call the backend.

Comment: That'll work fine unless you use `.failOnUnknown` on the adapter.

Comment: @EricCochran Thanx for answer. Accept